# script needs to add another loop

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

script which runs `netstat -tulpun | grep -i port_from_the_list` & takes the output for running the next command
I need to run 2 command on all the server mentioned in the list.

```
server: Jan port: 8000  
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1505/httpd  

server: feb port: 8000  
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1505/httpd
```

1. login to the server
2. run the first command `netstat` which gives the output of process id
3. `ps -ef | grep -i 1505 "processid"` runs it will take that process id output & run the command `ps`

Accepted output

```
server: Jan port: 8000  
tcp   0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 1505/httpd  

root      1421 15033  0 13:38 pts/16   00:00:00 grep -i 1505  

server: feb port: 8000  
tcp   0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 1505/httpd  

root      1421 15033  0 13:38 pts/16   00:00:00 grep -i 1505
```

I am unable to read the output of the `netstat` command and run the next.

```
while read -r -u10 server port line  
do  
echo ========== server: "$server" port: "$port" ==========  
ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpun | grep -E \"\b$port\b\"" | awk '{print $7}' | grep "/" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}' | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo Port % && ps -ef | grep % && echo ' | grep -v grep
echo   
done 10< demo
```

Comment: Unsure of what you're asking. Are you asking how to parse the output of `netstat` such that you can then run the `ps` command on the associated PID?

Comment: To the best that I know, `netstat` doesn't show you any process IDs (PIDs). On the other hand, your process may have the port number (1505 in your example) listed as an argument, in which case you should go with that and skip `netstat` command. Otherwise I am unable to understand your question, like the first comment author, Bratchley. As a side note, you can use `lsof` command, `grep` for the port number and parse the output for the PID if this is your intention.

Comment: @MelBurslan The `-p` option makes `netstat` show the PID and program name. `1505/httpd` means PID = 1505, program = httpd.

Comment: So far i have created this, but still the output is not upto the mark. I am not getting the output as required. please check the Question again.

Comment: Drop `netstat` - it's deprecated. And kinda broken. Use `ss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with

```
for port in $(cat demo); do
   mypid=$(netstat xxxx |
      grep ":${port} " | grep LISTEN | sed -e 's/.*LISTEN//'| cut -d/ -f1)
   ps -fp ${mypid}
done
```

Possiple changes (what you are familiar with):

- Use xargs for calling ps
  `... -f1) | xargs ps -fp`
- Use `sed` for cutting the /
- Use while loop
  `cat demo | while read port; do`